# Updating Two Tables At The Same Time T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cascade

I have created a table called `Sales_Details_Store1` and a second table called `Sales_Store1`.

They are tied together using RI with `Sale_ID` (increment 1,1 of bigint type) being the PK in the `Sales_Store1` table and the FK being the `Sale_ID` (bigint) in the `Sales_Details_Store1` table.

When declaring the RI between both tables I had used `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

The problem I am struggling with is that I need to have my FK updated with the incremented values from the PK, but be able to at the same time update both tables records.

I have had trouble sorting out a trigger or a transaction to do this. Any suggestions?

```
Sales_Store1
Sale_ID (PK, icrement(1,1), bigint, not null), 
Employee_ID (bigint, null), 
Customer_ID (bigint, null), 
Sale_Date (datetime, null), 
Taxes (money, null), 
Payment_Type (varchar, null), 
Notes (varchar, null), 
Tax_Rate (decimal, null), 
Tax_Status (int, null) 

Sales_Details_Store1
ID (PK, bigint, not null), 
Sale_ID (FK, bigint, null), 
Product_ID (bigint, null), 
Quantity (int, null), 
Unit_Price (decimal, null), 
Discount (decimal, null),
Date_Allocated (datetime, null),
Inventory_ID (bigint, null)
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to insert records at the same time within both tables and make sure that the FK values are cascaded from the PK.

Comment: Please provide the actual table definitions.  Not clear what you want to do.  What is RI?

Comment: Referential Integrity for RI.

Comment: Edit the question and format.

Comment: Still not clear what you are tying to do.  What is the use case to update a FK to a new PK?

Comment: So every time there is sale that is placed in the Sales_Store1 table there should be the ability to maintain referential integrity between said table and Sales_Details_Store1 by making sure the values match up between both the primary and foreign key constraint.

Comment: The primary key from Sales_Store1 is like an autonumber or it increments by 1 every time a new entry or record is created. This must stay the same in the second table (I would best assume by the use of cascading a primary key entry to the foreign key column...). Because of this I need a way to also enter records simultaneously to ensure the PK and FK constraint continue to properly increment. I am not sure if this makes any more sense?

Comment: I know what an identity is and how it works.   You are seriously confused.  There should be no FK rows to update with the creation of a new PK.  You insert a row get the new PK and then use it for the FK inserts.  Cascade is something different.

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Where's your code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really sound like a cascading problem to me. It sounds more like, you need the identity value from the first table when you insert into the second table.

Inside a transaction, you should insert into Sales_Store1, then get the ID(s) (either by [Scope_Identity()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql) or use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) statement), and then insert the data into Sales_Details_Store1 providing the primary key you got the prior step .

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale (SaleID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,SaleDate DATETIME2)
CREATE TABLE SaleDetail (SaleDetailID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,SaleID BIGINT,ItemDesc NVARCHAR(200))
GO


BEGIN TRAN t1;
INSERT INTO Sale(SaleDate) SELECT GETDATE();
DECLARE @SaleID BIGINT=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO SaleDetail (SaleID,ItemDesc) SELECT @SaleID,'Test'
COMMIT TRAN t1;
--ROLLBACK TRAN t1;
GO

SELECT * FROM Sale
SELECT * FROM SaleDetail
GO
```

Comment: Yes, would you have an example of this? I am a student so I am learning.

Comment: @ArielGelman I would recommend researching transactions a bit more as my example is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: @ArielGelman If this solved your problem, feel free to accept this answer by checking the answer's checkbox